# Configuring squid so that browser doesn't prompt for login/password

Tags: squid, webproxy

At the company where I work, we have a web proxy and the browser prompts for login/pass every time I open it. After seeing this, I installed squid in my computer, configure my company web proxy as a parent cache in my squid.conf (with my login:password).
I set my browser settings to use my IP as the web proxy.

The problem is: when I visit some sites (it doesn't happen to every site), I'm prompted for user/password, even though I haven't configured squid to ask for authentication. I can click "cancel" and continue visiting the site without typing my credentials.

AFAIK, I wouldn't have to type my credentials, as my squid isn't configured to authenticate the user (at least I'm thinking it's not).

Why does this happen? How can I turn this prompt off? How can I configure my squid for not ask credentials? Thanks in advance.

My `squid.conf` is:

```
acl all src all
http_port 3128
http_access allow all
cache_peer 10.20.0.100 parent 3128 0 no-query default login=username:password
never_direct allow all
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, after some tests with another browser, I found out that only Firefox (among those browsers I've tested) prompted for credentials. With that in mind, I think the "problem" is not Squid. If someone is experiencing this with Firefox, try changing the browser and see whether the problem keeps or not.

I hope this can help someone else.

EDIT: I made some tests with Chromium and Konqueror (besides Firefox). None of them prompted for credentials.